# How to make each TestCase call a hook after setUp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

In my project I have a subclass of TestCase (call it BaseTest) which does some stuff to prepare and then reset the testing environment, and a large number of actual test case subclasses (about 80) which each have their own unique setUp methods.

I want each of the individual test case subclasses to call a particular hook at the end of their setUp methods. I would like to do this without making a change to every one of those methods.

Basically, the situation looks roughly like this example file:

```
import unittest


class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        print('prepping env')

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        print('resetting env')

    def post_setup_hook(self):
        print('in post_setup_hook')


class TestFeatureA(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        print('prepping a')

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()

    def test_0(self):
        print('testing a0')

    def test_1(self):
        print('testing a1')


class TestFeatureB(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        print('prepping b')

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()

    def test_0(self):
        print('testing b0')

    def test_1(self):
        print('testing b1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I would like the result of running `python -m unittest example` to print 'in post setup hook' after each time it prints 'prepping a' or 'prepping b', but without modifying TestFeatureA or TestFeatureB. Can this be done?

Note that I'm using python 3.6. I don't think this will run in python 2.x.

Comment: why can't you call `post_setup_hook` in `BaseTest.setUp`? order matters?

Comment: Yes, the whole point is that it must be called after TestFeatureA.setUp, which is why it's called post_setup_hook instead of sometime_during_setup_hook.

Comment: `Python` standard library is good, but `unittest` is not, especially for something serious, you definitely should take a look at [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Did you notice that I said I had 80 test classes? Most of them have several test cases. Some of those test cases are _very_ complicated. Can I switch to pytest without rewriting them?

Comment: yeap, AFAIK `pytest` supports tests written with `unittest` and allows you to rewrite your tests step-by-step to using fixtures and other awesome things

Comment: can it do the thing i'm trying to do here though?

Comment: using fixtures makes you free from `setUp` and `tearDown` methods at all, you define small functions returning desired objects and that's it, than you pass your fixtures by names into functions and `pytest` generates them for each test case

Comment: don't know a lot about your situation, why you need some operations to be done right after `setUp`, but i'm sure that this will go away with `pytest`, cuz architecture of your tests will definetely change (also you can still use `xUnit` style with classes and setups/teardowns, but it is not how work is done in `pytest` world)

Comment: I have 80 test classes. "architecture of your tests will definitely change" means "no, this won't work."

Comment: if you are assuming that changing `unittest` to `pytest` will write code for you, well, it will not

Comment: will it at least wax my floors?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the [`run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/case.py#L566) method of `BaseTest(TestCase)` to call `post_setup_hook` [after the `setUp`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/case.py#L597).

Just copy-paste the `run` method into `BaseTest` and add the `post_setup_hook` call after `setUp` is run.

Comment: wow, that's ugly! works though, since I can put the run override in a separate class/file

Answer (score 1):

What about using a decorator here?

```
def post_setup(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('in post_setup_hook')
        f(*args)  # execute BaseTest setUp
        print(args[0].FOO)  # Access BasteTest class attribute
        print(args[0].foo)  # Access BasteTest object foo attribute
        print('out post_setup_hook')
    return wrapper


class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    FOO = 'BAR'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foo = 'bar'

    @post_setup
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        print('BaseTest - prepping env')

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        print('BaseTest - resetting env')


class TestFeatureA(BaseTest):
    def test_0(self):
        print('TestFeatureA - testing a0')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
in post_setup_hook
BaseTest - prepping env
BAR
bar
out post_setup_hook
TestFeatureA - testing a0
BaseTest - resetting env
```

Comment: Doesn't work; post-setup-hook is called before setup, not after

Comment: Please refer to "in post_setup_hook" and "out post_setup_hook" in the code and output... A decorator function allows to execute specific code before and/or after the decorated function's code.

Comment: 'in post-setup-hook' and 'out post-setup-hook' should both have been printed after ''prepping a' (which you took out, defeating the purpose of the exercise)